# How to use docker compose v2 in pipelines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

How can I target the v2 of docker compose using a private container registry from service connections in pipelines ?
I cannot find any way to do so in the [DockerComposeV0 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker-compose?view=azure-devops).

And using bash directly is not practical as I need to access my container registry from service connections.